# WordPress - Using Conditionals with Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, custom-fields

My code below is not outputting the values. I think it has something to do with how I've concatenated the echo strings. If I strip away the HTML tags it will output, but I need to add styling.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
<?php
    $location = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'location', true );
    $date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date', true );
    $season = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'season', true );
    if( !empty( $location ) && !empty($date) && !empty($season) ) {
        echo '<div class="post-extras">';
        echo '<p>' . 'Wedding Location: ' . $location . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . 'Shoot Date: ' . $date . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . 'Season: ' . $season . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: what you mean better way? so you dont have that much `echo`? you try to use for example `if($allthingshere):` and close it like `endif;` then you can have normal html inside

Comment: I meant a 'cleaner' way, using less code. It felt too heavy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can do it like this as well.

```
<?php if( !empty( $location ) && !empty($date) && !empty($season) ):?>
<div class="post-extras">
     <p>Wedding Location: <?php echo $location;?></p>
     <p>Shoot Date: <?php echo $date;?></p>
     <p>Season: <?php echo $season; ?></p>
</div>
<?php else:?>
  <h4>Sorry, nothing to show.</h4>
<?php endif;?>
```

**Update**

```
<?php 
$location = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'location', true ); 
$date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date', true ); 
$season = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'season', true ); 
if( $location && $date && $season ): ?>
     <div class="post-extras">
     <p>Wedding Location: <?php echo $location?></p> 
     <p>Shoot Date: <?php echo $date?></p> 
     <p>Season: <?php echo $season?></p> 
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

and to debug it, you add something like this so you are sure you are getting the right values, or any values out of the get_post_meta

```
$location = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'location', true );
printf("values is %s", $location); 
$date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date', true ); 
printf("values is %s", $date);
$season = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'season', true );
printf("values is %s", $season);
```

and in case you only want to show the values you actually have:: you can use this::

```
<?php 
$location = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'location', true ); 
$date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date', true ); 
$season = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'season', true ); ?>
 <div class="post-extras">
<?php
if( $location): ?>
     <p>Wedding Location: <?php echo $location?></p> 
<?php endif;?>
<?php if($date):?>
     <p>Shoot Date: <?php echo $date?></p> 
<?php endif;?>
<?php if($season):?>
     <p>Season: <?php echo $season?></p> 
<?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Comment: This one looks cleaner, but it's still not working for me. I don't understand.

Comment: @NatashaMcd do you get any values from those variables? maybe one of them return in empty so the condition is never met... use `else:` to output something

Comment: Okay I got it to output now. I had to have values for all three in order for it to execute. I need the conditional to say, if there's at least one value, to output the html. Is it the '&&' that's wrong for expressing that? I think I need an OR in there.

Comment: yes, if you dont need all those conditions to be meet, them is better to have `||` instead

Comment: I added '||' but it now executes all the html, even if there isn't values for them. So if there is a value for 'date' only, it will still show location: and season:

Comment: you use `&&` so all condition is meet, and `||` so when any of the conditions is meet.  so you want something that is in between that?

Comment: I have three variables. I only want to show the output of the variable and the html if there is a value attached to that specific variable. Otherwise it's displaying empty fields. :)

Comment: you can only do that jsfiddle for html, css and js.. i dont think it will work since is php and wordpress.... but you can use coderunner if you have a mac.. and here is a small sample test..`<?php
 $location = "Hello"; 
 $date = ""; 
 $season = ""; 
 if( $location && $date && $season ):
  echo "Hello world";
 else:
 echo "Nothing";
 endif;
?>`

Comment: Yah I know, I just mostly wanted to show you the code, not how it was executing. I didn't know where else to put it. I'll check out coderunner.

Comment: try any of the updates. they should work, looks like is some variables are not returning any value.

Comment: Almost there! What is the php operator for 'OR'? Here is the link: http://jessicalittlephotography.com/stage/kim-adam-fall-engagement/ As you can see, it outputs all three but there is only a value for one. I don't want to see the empty values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

```
echo <<<EOT

  <div class="post-extras">
    <p>Wedding Location: {$location}</p>
    <p>Shoot Date: {$date}</p>
    <p>Season: {$season}</p>
  </div>

EOT;
```

This is called a [Heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document), and is particularly useful in [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for printing/echoing blocks of HTML code with visible  indentation. The ability to throw a variable in there is pretty useful too.

Comment: Ok great, thanks. I got this to output, but it's not outputting the value. It outputs the variable as text rather then it's value. I have the whole div wrapped in these: ''

Comment: there is no need to wrap `div` in quotation marks. Have you checked that the variables are working with a simple `echo $date; echo $season;` etc before testing within the Heredoc? There shouldn't be any reason why you can't output variable values within PHP Heredoc. Remember that the last `EOT;` statement must appear on it's own line, and at the very beginning of the line (no whitespace before it).